# How to display FormGroup with dynamic data in Angular reactive form?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've one reactive form where inside a FormGroup I've adding data dynamically from one external source & trying to render those data in the component.I can able to add the data dynamically but at the time of rendering I can't able to understand how to render those.

Here is my Stackblitz sample code (https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-l78yjm?file=src%2Fmain.ts) where onclick of "Render Project Tables" button I'm adding the data to the FormGroup. After adding the data tables are rendering but with following errors as shown screenshot. The data(min/max) I'm trying to rendering are editable. That's why I'm trying to render inside the "input" form field.But, this is the place where I'm getting confuse how to access those data & put inside the form input fields.

**Expected Output -**

The expected output of this will be like this where min/max will be html input form field value which user can able to update also -
[image]

[image]

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <div>
    <button type="button" (click)="renderProjectsTable()">Render Project Tables</button>
    <form [formGroup]="MRO" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div formGroupName="constraints">
        <div *ngFor="let obj of constraintsFormArr.controls | keyvalue; let i = index; let l = last"
        [formGroupName]="i">
          <table border=1>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Parameter</th>
                <th>Min</th>
                <th>Max</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <!-- Placeholder for Param -->
                </td>
                <td>
                  <!-- Placeholder for Min -->
                  <input type="text">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <!-- Placeholder for Max -->
                  <input type="text">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.addDefaultRow();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  MRO!: FormGroup;

  addDefaultRow() {
    this.MRO = this.formBuilder.group({
      constraints: this.formBuilder.group({}),
    });
  }

  get constraintsFormArr() {
    return this.MRO.get('constraints') as FormGroup;
  }

  addProjTbl(){
    this.constraintsFormArr.addControl('proj1', this.formBuilder.array([
      {
        param: 'AAA1',
        min: 11,
        max: 21,
      },
      {
        param: 'AAA2',
        min: 31,
        max: 41,
      }
    ]));

    this.constraintsFormArr.addControl('proj2', this.formBuilder.array([
      {
        param: 'BBB1',
        min: 110,
        max: 210,
      },
      {
        param: 'BBB2',
        min: 310,
        max: 410,
      }
    ]));
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log('MRO form values: ', this.MRO)
  }

  renderProjectsTable(){
    this.addProjTbl()
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Comment: You are passing the index (`i`) to `[formGroupName]` directive. You need to pass the name as the directive suggests

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Do u mean, I need to pass like this - ```[formGroupName]="constraints"``` ?

Comment: But `constraintsFormArr` does not have groups, right? It has `FormArray` controls. So you may want to try to iterate over the controls of `constraintsFormArr`, and with a secondary `*ngFor`, iterate over the controls in each `FormArray`

Comment: This may be helpful: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/

Comment: As @HarunYilmaz mentioned, `constraints` should be of type `FormArray` and not `FormGroup`. I tried [updating it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4shbef?file=src%2Fmain.ts) and the error disappeared, but I'm not sure if it fits your use case.

Comment: @riorudo I've added my expected output. Now, it'll probably give you a better idea what exactly I want it achieve.